# "Value does not fall within the expected range" on trying to read color from an image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, image-processing

I have this image:

[image]

and its details are as follows:

[image]

I am trying to find any specified color in this image by using following code:

```
private void UpdateCursorEllipse(Color searchColor)
{
  // Scan the canvas image for a color which matches the search color
  CroppedBitmap cb;
  Color tempColor = new Color();
  byte[] pixels = new byte[4];
  int searchY = 0;
  int searchX = 0;
  searchColor.A = 255;
  for (searchY = 0; searchY <= canvasImage.Width - 1; searchY++)
  {
    for (searchX = 0; searchX <= canvasImage.Height - 1; searchX++)
    {
      cb = new CroppedBitmap(ColorImage.Source as BitmapSource, new Int32Rect(searchX, searchY, 1, 1));
      cb.CopyPixels(pixels, 4, 0);
      tempColor = Color.FromArgb(255, pixels[2], pixels[1], pixels[0]);
      if (tempColor == searchColor) break;
    }
    if (tempColor == searchColor) break;
  }
```

XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray"
                    BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
            <Image x:Name="ColorImage"
                   Source="Images/Spectrum.jpg" Stretch="None"></Image>
            <Canvas x:Name="canvasImage"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    MouseDown="canvasImage_MouseDown"
                    MouseUp="canvasImage_MouseUp"
                    MouseMove="canvasImage_MouseMove"
                    Width="175"
                    Height="150">
                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipsePixel"
                         Width="8"
                         Height="8"
                         Stroke="Black"
                         Fill="White"
                         Canvas.Left="0"
                         Canvas.Top="0" />
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
```

The Problem is i am getting "Value does not fall within the expected range" error inside the for loop.
Any idea what might i be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: for which value? surely you can trace this

Comment: any value, I tried it for red (#ff0000).

Comment: Verify values in pixels[2], pixels[1], pixels[0], they shouldn't be bigger than 255

Comment: This code doesnt really achieve anything, so whether if finds or doesnt find, it does the same...  Are you sure canvasImage is the same size as your picture?

Comment: @BugFinder yes you can see the image details , canvas and the image dimensions are the same. if the color is found it sets the ellipse position on the particular point in the canvas and if not it sets the ellipse to the top left corner, i havent pasted that code.

Comment: any other approach that could give me the position of the color in the canvas ?

Comment: looks like its gonna be my third consecutive unanswered question here on SO. i am on a hat-trick !!

Comment: The source bitmap has 24 bits per pixel, so check if the CroppedBitmap also has that. Then you shouldn't try to copy four bytes out of it, but only three.

Comment: Besides that you don't need a CroppedBitmap at all. Call the [CopyPixels overload with a sourceRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616042(v=vs.110).aspx) on the original BitmapSource.

Comment: Moreover, your loops should go to `canvasImage.Width` and `canvasImage.Height`, but instead to the `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` of the source bitmap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121919/discussion-between-sameed-and-clemens).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a method like this to get the `Color` of a pixel in a BitmapSource:

```
private static Color GetPixelColor(BitmapSource bitmap, int x, int y)
{
    if (bitmap.Format == PixelFormats.Bgr24 ||
        bitmap.Format == PixelFormats.Bgr32)
    {
        var pixel = new byte[bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8];
        bitmap.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1), pixel, pixel.Length, 0);
        return Color.FromRgb(pixel[2], pixel[1], pixel[0]);
    }

    if (bitmap.Format == PixelFormats.Bgra32)
    {
        var pixel = new byte[4];
        bitmap.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1), pixel, pixel.Length, 0);
        return Color.FromArgb(pixel[3], pixel[2], pixel[1], pixel[0]);
    }

    if (bitmap.Format == PixelFormats.Rgb24)
    {
        var pixel = new byte[bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8];
        bitmap.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1), pixel, pixel.Length, 0);
        return Color.FromRgb(pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2]);
    }

    // other formats

    return new Color();
}
```

Then loop over all pixel like this to find a certain Color:

```
private static bool FindColor(BitmapSource bitmap, Color color, out int x, out int y)
{
    x = 0;

    for (y = 0; y < bitmap.PixelHeight; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < bitmap.PixelWidth; x++)
        {
            if (GetPixelColor(bitmap, x, y) == color)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```